# npm install from vso

Tags: node.js, git, npm, azure-devops

I'm just going to throw all this out there and hope SO can help..

My situation is that I need to `npm install -s` from a **Visual Studio Online hosted git repo**.   I have seen how to do this from github and bitbucket.  I guessed that the process would be the same but when I run npm install, nothing happens. I expected that at a minimum, the index.js, the readme.md and the package.json would be pulled.

I created a simple repo at `https://ldcjtctest.visualstudio.com/_git/MyFirstProject`

this project contains these files:

[image: project file structure]

I have tried running npm install with ssh and https but both give me the following with verbose logging:[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching, I discovered that the quickest way to accomplish what I wanted was to create a feed.  I just followed [the MS documentation on how to do this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/feeds/create-feed).

*Note:  I had an issue when following the instructions linked here.  I kept getting an **unauthorized** error.  It took me a while, but I found out that when running the command `vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc`, my .npmrc file was not being created locally, but on a shared drive.  when I moved that file to `c:/users/<yourself>/` it worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Steps for Https:

1. [Create personal access token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate#create-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate-access)
2. Command:`npm install git+https://test:[personal access token]@[account name].visualstudio.com/[team project]/_git/[repository]`.

Steps for SSH:

1. [General SSH key without passphrase and add the public key to your VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate).
2. Optional, run `git clone` with ssh to do test to make sure the SSH key works fine
3. Command `npm install git+[ssh address]`.

Note: Tested with 3.10.10 (npm -v)

Comment: It appears that when i follow the instructions and run `npm publish` for the feed, it is still publishing to the NPM registry.  Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?  I thought it would publish to the feed not NPM.

Comment: I found my issue and added it to my answer.